# how to get the probabilty of click an ad after the nth impression?

Tags: statistics

Ive got 2 tables, clicks and impressions.

The clicks table saves the clicks that a user made to an advertise, its something like; advertise id, user id, time of click

The impressions table saves the impressions that a user made to an advertise its like; advertise id, user id, time of impression

For ranking the ads i am using the CTR; total clicks for the advertise/ total impressions for the advertise

A few days ago i notice that usually the users that dont make a click after the second impression never click the advertise, do you know how i can use this data to rank the advertises per user?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, the CTR will be enough to rank the advertisements on a **per user** basis, (clicks/impressions -> zero as impressions increase).

However, if you want to rank the impressions **globally**, (not just per user), perhaps you could use some sort of threshold value, (i.e. ignore CTR where clicks = 0).

Also, it might be worth looking into **Position Normalized CTR**. This article is somewhat outdated but you might find it useful:

http://certifiedknowledge.org/blog/google-adwords-quality-score-factors-demystified/